# how to run ios6 simulator in xcode5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, ios6.1

I upgraded my xcode to xcode5，In the directory

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`
I got `iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/` and `iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/`

In the directory `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`
I got `iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/`和`iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/`

Every time when I ran my app, I can't select the version of the iOS, nor can I select I resolution other than retina. The Xcode5 always use a retina resolution with iOS7:

[image]

But what I want to use is the low resolution with iOS6, how could I do?
ps:
I have set the following settings to iOS6.1

`General -> Deployment Target`

`Build Setting -> Base SDK`

I did have downloaded the iOS 6.0 simulator, but I do not have option to use that.

[image]

Comment: First download the Simulator of IOS 6 from Xcode-> Preferences-> Downloads. once it is download then it will automatically show option for ios 6 simulator.

Comment: And set your deployment target to 6.0, since the 6.0 simulator won't be available if the target is 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

With iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1 simulator **both installed**, the problem got solved!

Answer (score 2):

### Initially go to more simulators

[image]

### Then A window will open up

[image]

### Now Download And Install 6.0 /6.1 as you want

[image]

### After successfully Installation it will show up like that

[image]

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: According to my experience, you have to install the iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1 both, but thank you all the same, you provide me with lots of pictures.

Comment: Well, you can give me a plus

Answer (score 1):

Download Xcode 4.6 dmg file from the apple dev center.

Double click dmg file.
Mount it.
After then you can automatically use the simulator 6.

Alternatively you can also add the simulator 6 from the Xcode 5 also.
But the base SDK will remain 7.0 for Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode preference and install the simulators
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode5 preference and install the simulators

[image]

Comment: I did installed iOS 6.0 simulator, but I did not have the option to select the version os iOS. I am trying to download the 6.1 simulator and see if this works.

Comment: I installed the iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1 simulator both, it finally worked

Comment: @welkinwalker Thats nice...:) happy coding.. :)